# DarkActionBar on pre lollipop doesn't have white icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I think i've tried everything on the Internet but nothing seems to work. The icons always stay gray but I want them white. Isn't that purpose of DarkActionBar?

```
<style name="AppTheme"
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/one</item>
```

What it looks like on 4.4 and on 5.0. I want the 5.0 look.
[image]

[image]

Comment: it doesnt work in version 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have in my project, it works just fine:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/scroller_style</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/statbar_bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statbar_bg</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/statbar_bg</item>

    <!-- <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item> -->
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- Overflow menu -->
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

I would also suggest you to check for different style/theme files in different values folders, maybe something is overriding.